# Can rails server also start memcache if it isn't started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

Can you make the command 'rails server' also start memcached if it isn't started?

Comment: For development this might be expedient, but for production you do NOT want to do this, as you'll probably be running multiple servers and you don't want each one trying to start memcached.

Comment: i meant the command 'rails server'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make that script do lots of things, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to do so. You should use a tool designed for the job of keeping processes up, like [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

On a development box, I still probably wouldn't hack my rails script, but would instead write a shell script that does both things for me.

**Edit: Responding to the comments below.**

Alright, here's the simplest possible shell script. You can store it anywhere (like `/usr/local/bin`), but you need to be in a RAILS_ROOT directory to run it.

`dev_servers.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
memcached -d
rails server
```

Comment: ah ok, that sounds like a good idea thanks, is the shell script tricky?

Comment: I don't think it would be hard at all, because if I remember correctly `memcached -d` won't start a new server if there is one already running. You wouldn't have to check for anything, just run that command in your shell script then run `rails server`.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* create an initializer that does it:

```
# config/initializers/start_memcache.rb
if Rails.env.development?
  `/usr/local/bin/memcached -d -m 8 -l 127.0.0.1 &`
end
```

**WARNING**: I haven't tested this for suitability.